# jQuery using "split" correctly

Tags: jquery

I have a `var` called title, that I am using in a rest driven search query. The search works, but it only filters if the word matches exactly what the title has. The issue is that sometimes the search may be close or have part of the title, I am trying to using `split` to break up the title-maybe if the first 3 letters of the word matches or if title matches. How can I extend my code to accommodate this?

I tried using "`split`" but

```
var Title = $(#txtSkill").val();
var res = Title.split("");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Title.split("")` will split the string into an array of individual letters like `["v","a","l","u","e"]`

What you want here is [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) which will:

> extract characters from indexStart up to but not including indexEnd.

```
var Title = $("#txtSkill").val(); 
var res = Title.substring(0,3);
```